# Why can't small trans-cycloalkenes exist?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Why when a ring has 8 carbon's and contains a double bond the trans version is very unstable to exist, for instance a molecule like cholesterol?

Comment: Are you asking why a trans configuration of a double bond in an eight membered cyclic system is less stable than the cis configuration?

Comment: Yes, i was asked a question whether a molecule of cholesterol displays cis-trans isomerism at the C=C bond.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're stuck in the ring structure.

The trans isomer has branches that, in their natural state, would want to rest antiparallel to one another. But in double bond 6 membered ring structure (like in cholesterol), these bonds would need to be twisted a lot so that they could sit in the octagonal ring structure. Given how a double bond is rigid and will already resist rotation, this theoretical trans isomer will have such a high energy requirement for it to exist that it will simply refuse to do so.

Comment: *trans*-cyclooctene is stable at room temperature.